# Boolean Law that proves theorem

Tags: boolean-algebra

What Boolean Law proves the following theorem:

```
(a && b) || (b && c) || (a && c) = (a || b) && (b || c) && (a || c)
```

I made a truth table for both of them and they are equal, but I'm not able to prove it.

I'd prefer some hints instead of the full answer.

Comment: If you made a truth table for both and they're equal, then that IS the proof.

Comment: @2012ssohn It's a book exercise, and it asks you to probe it using Boolean Laws

Comment: Proving is for mathematicians. Probing is for space aliens and proctologists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use the convention that $a+b$ means `a || b` and $ab = a \cdot b$ means `a && b`.    Note that each distributes over the other, so that
$$
a(b + c) = ab + ac\\
a + bc = (a + b)(a + c)
$$
As you may verify via truth table.  Now, noting that $x^2 = x$, $x + x = x$, and $1+x = 1$ for all $x$, we can state that
$$
\begin{align}
(a + b)(b +c)(c+a) &=
bca + bcc + bba + bbc + aca + acc + aba + abc\\
&= abc + ab + bc + ac\\
&= ab(c+1) + bc + ac\\
&= ab + bc + ac
\end{align}
$$
As desired.